# public database of cloudkit to store user's sensitive data in encrypted form

Tags: ios, iphone, backup, cloudkit

I am new to ios development. I am developing an application where, users stores some data in database. I have used sqlite database to store the data locally.

Now I want to provide backup facility for the local storage. I have read about cloud kit. There are private and public database in cloudkit. And if we store data in private database, then  it is visible only to the current user and is stored in that user’s iCloud account.

But I want to use public database, so that the data is stored in app's icloud account and user's icould storage will remain intact for his other usage. I am planning to convert sqlite database to json or xml format, encrypt it and then store to icloud public database. When user wants the backup of his data, he will get the encrypted file, which will be decrypted at client side, and then converted to sqlite and stored. The password will be known only to the user.

I don't know this is a good idea or not? Or Should I use private database to store user's sensitive data?

Thanks in advance,

Krishna

Comment: Probably best to use a private database. For passwords and other sensitive data it also good practice to use keychain storage.

Comment: Thank you fighton for your reply.

Comment: Thank you fighton for your reply.  As you said, Private database would be best. But the data that user will store will be large, more than 1 GB.  And if it is stored on public database, than that user's private icloud storage will not be used, and user can use that for other applications. The data will be encrypted and no one can see the actual data.  So is this ok to store in public database??

Comment: I think it would be ok. However if the sensitive data you are storing is passwords or credit card information, it is probably best practice to use keychain or another well known API such as stripe (for credit cards)

Comment: You’ve probably decided on this already, but if you have a lot of users the public database is not unlimited. Although it’s capped at 1PB you only have access to that amount once you hit 4 million users. You should look at the limits and see if using the public database is feasible. http://developer.apple.com/icloud/CloudKit